# React Tabs content

Tags: reactjs

I was playing around with React for the first time and trying to figure out how to make tabs. I found an outline of the code that looks simple and clean enough (do correct me if I'm wrong though, please), but I don't know how to show the content of the tabs outside of the 'constructor'. As I want the tab content to be more than just a couple of words, and the current code seems constricting.

This is the part that I'm talking about:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeTabIndex: 0,
      initialData: [
        {
          label: 'Tab 1',
          content: 'Content 1',
        },
        {
          label: 'Tab 2',
          content: 'Content 2',
        },
        {
          label: 'Tab 3',
          content: 'Content 3',
        },
      ],
    };
    this.handleTabClick = this.handleTabClick.bind(this);
  }
```

How do I pull the content outside of this, if I have too much content to be put inside that? Here is the entire code outline: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/apgrwnqyo). Any suggestions/links are welcome.

And I apologize if I'm explaining this wrong, I'm still trying to figure stuff out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a Component you want to render in Tab Content and assign it to content.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Tabs from "./Tabs";
import Content from "./Content";

export default class TabView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeTabIndex: 0,
      initialData: [
        {
          label: "Tab 1",
          content: <TabContent />
        },
        {
          label: "Tab 2",
          content: "Content 2"
        },
        {
          label: "Tab 3",
          content: "Content 3"
        }
      ]
    };
    this.handleTabClick = this.handleTabClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleTabClick(index) {
    this.setState({
      activeTabIndex: index
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { initialData, activeTabIndex } = this.state;
    const activeItem = this.state.initialData[activeTabIndex];
    return (
      <div>
        <Tabs
          handleTabClick={this.handleTabClick}
          data={this.state.initialData}
          activeTabIndex={activeTabIndex}
        />
        <Content content={activeItem.content} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const TabContent = () => (
  <div>
    <p>I am here</p>
  </div>
);
```